# better style to create multiple property from the same class

Tags: python

I would like to create a class with multiple properties from the same existing class. I have following code, but it seems like it is really poor style ... any better way to do it?

```
class employee:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class company():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = employee('a')
        self.b = employee('b')
        self.c = employee('c')
        self.d = employee('d')
        self.e = employee('e')
        self.f = employee('f')

t = company()
```

Comment: I'd say more than few and you want to put them into a container instead, like a list or a dict. What a "few" means can be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Also, please do not spam the Python tags. Your question will only ever *require* a generic [python] tag. If your question is version *specific* then feel free to add a version specific tag in addition to the generic one. However, a Python 2 and a Python 3 tag is almost never good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want your class more flexible than this: you want to allow a company to add and remove employees.  This will require a different approach to the interface.  Something like

```
class employee:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class company():
    def __init__(self):
        self.employee_list = []

    # create and add a new employee
    def hire(self, new_name):
        new_employee = employee(new_name)
        self.employee_list.append(new_employee)


t = company()
for new_hire in ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f']:
    t. hire(new_hire)
```

Note that the `for` loop is probably *not* how you will actually populate your company.  I did that just to make it easy to do something equivalent to your original code.